# Hedge removal to lawn

Tags: lawn, hedge

newbie here!

I’m looking at a little project to remove a (well existing) hedge that former part of our back garden when we bought a newbuild.
There’s a fence behind the hedge.
There’s a gradient drop to about 30cm below the current lawn level to the bottom of the fence.

I don’t want to just dig the hedge trees out and fill in with topsoil(etc) as it’ll all lay against the wooden fence directly.

Any tips or guides on what I could do?
Do I need a retaining wall?
Could I get away with laying some subbase somehow?
Or should I layer up some sleepers?

The result should be a level continuation of the lawn.

Thanks!!

Comment: What is the other side of the fence, off your own property? Are the levels there 30cm below your lawn too?

Comment: Interesting question. If could provide an overall illustration, & an illustration of the base of the fence & base of the hedges, that could help to visualise it; and if presently is lawn growing on the entire ground surface and on under the fence, & the distance gap under the fence

Comment: Thanks for the replies. 
Other side of the fence is council land, which does slope away. Not sure to what gradient. There is lawn/grass growing all the way through, save for about a meter wide section underneath the hedge. 
I can indeed to an illustration if that helps?

Comment: Yes, illustrations would be quite helpful, and also the specific distances over which the ground level changes & how much the level changes over each of those distances, and where those different grade sections are located relative the hedge & fence(sounds like at least two or three such features/sections).